# Using Dynamo DB client in my custom ask-sdk webhook

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I have used my own custom webhook using ask-sdk and is deployed in my ec2 instance. Now I want to use DynamoDB as DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter
but I am not getting any reference how to do that.

DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter will need AWS Keys and table name and some details for dynamo db but where to initialize? I found some code, but this dont have anything :

```
persistenceAdapter = new DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter({ 
        tableName: 'global_attr_table',
        createTable: true,
        partitionKeyGenerator: keyGenerator
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be solved by adding environmental variables and by setting up an AWS CLI profile:

Heres how you setup an AWS CLI Profile:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Once you have a profile setup with your AWS access information you can export Environmental Variables in your command line or in a shell script

```
$> export AWS_PROFILE=YourNewAWSCLIProfileName
$> export AWS_REGION=us-east-1
$> export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
```

and you can check that these variables are set by typing

```
$> echo $AWS_PROFILE
$> echo $AWS_REGION
$> echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
```

This is what I use.  If for some reason that doesnt work here is some research into how you might add a DynamoDB Client:

Trying to solve a different problem so let me solve yours as I walk through mine:
In: node_modules/ask-sdk/dist/skill/factory/StandardSkillFactory.js
there is reference to something similar to what you have above

```
new ask_sdk_dynamodb_persistence_adapter_1.DynamoDbPersistenceAdapter({
     tableName: thisTableName,
     createTable: thisAutoCreateTable,
     partitionKeyGenerator: thisPartitionKeyGenerator,
     dynamoDBClient: thisDynamoDbClient,
})
```

I believe you need to create a DynamoDbClient instance which I found referenced here in the AWS SDK Docs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-document-client.html

You'd have to set your own service: 
In: node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/dynamodb/document_client.js

```
  /**
   * Creates a DynamoDB document client with a set of configuration options.
   *
   * @option options params [map] An optional map of parameters to bind to every
   *   request sent by this service object.
   * @option options service [AWS.DynamoDB] An optional pre-configured instance
   *  of the AWS.DynamoDB service object to use for requests. The object may
   *  bound parameters used by the document client.
   * @option options convertEmptyValues [Boolean] set to true if you would like
   *  the document client to convert empty values (0-length strings, binary
   *  buffers, and sets) to be converted to NULL types when persisting to
   *  DynamoDB.
   * @see AWS.DynamoDB.constructor
   *
   */
  constructor: function DocumentClient(options) {
    var self = this;
    self.options = options || {};
    self.configure(self.options);
  },

  /**
   * @api private
   */
  configure: function configure(options) {
    var self = this;
    self.service = options.service;
    self.bindServiceObject(options);
    self.attrValue = options.attrValue =
      self.service.api.operations.putItem.input.members.Item.value.shape;
  },

  /**
   * @api private
   */
  bindServiceObject: function bindServiceObject(options) {
    var self = this;
    options = options || {};

    if (!self.service) {
      self.service = new AWS.DynamoDB(options);
    } else {
      var config = AWS.util.copy(self.service.config);
      self.service = new self.service.constructor.__super__(config);
      self.service.config.params =
        AWS.util.merge(self.service.config.params || {}, options.params);
    }
  },
```

I'm not sure what those options might look like.

Comment: it is throwing 'Could not create table (FooTableNew): Missing region in config', even though i have done export AWS_REGION=us-east-q

Comment: @stackjohnny us-east-q is not an AWS availability zone.  the aws availability zone would be us-east-1.  this is a list of zones: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html